# Is there a way to bypass the restriction in discord.py that if you plan on giving a multi-worded argument to a command, you must cover it in quotes?

Tags: python, discord.py, quotes

Take this example.

```
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, text)
    await ctx.send(text)
```

And let's say a user uses this command like this:

```
example Hello world
```

The bot would send "hello" to the chat. Only if the user covers the sentence in quotes would the bot send the whole sentence.

So, back to my question - is there a way to bypass this "restriction"? I want the program to be able to return the whole sentence even if the user didn't use quotes.

Comment: Try `async def example(ctx, *, text): await ctx.send(text)`

Comment: @GhostOps shouldn't that be `ctx.send(" ".join(text))?  I don't use discord so could be wrong

Comment: @2e0byo nope check it again....

Comment: @GhostOps Oh bother, I'm daft, sorry.... missed the ,

Comment: @2e0byo its ok, i changed it in the edit, lol

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Try the `*` as a parameter in your function, it pushes all the upcoming input to the `text` parameter

```py
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, *, text)
    await ctx.send(text)
```

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: this is a wrong answer to this question. it merely forces the `text` argument to be by keyword only. it does not change the semantics at all.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do u mean? the OP said he want to consider all the words passed with the command as a single sentence, does this cause u any issues when u tried it?

Comment: pardon my reaction. I did not anticipate that this library abuses python syntax like that and actually seems to introspect the command callback's parameter list to determine this situation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so u want the command to read all the words passed with the command as a list like *args?

Comment: I was under the impression that that would have to be done. I did not know that discord.py introspects the function's signature and treats a single keyword-only argument as "pass the raw command in there, whatever the parameter's name is". I have never seen this done and that is definitely not how python is supposed to be used. It is documented in discord.py however.